# Change prometheus endpoint using micrometer.io

Tags: java, metrics, prometheus, micrometer

I use micrometer metrics for prometheus and according to docs:
http://micrometer.io/docs/prometheus#_configuring

> A Spring Boot Actuator endpoint will be wired to /prometheus that
>   presents a Prometheus scrape with the appropriate format.

How to wire it to another endpoint like `/metrics`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the endpoint using the normal Spring Boot Actuator mechanism like so:

```
endpoints:
  prometheus:
    id: micrometheus
```

Here is a [reference](http://micrometer.io/docs/prometheus#_configuring) to the Micrometer documentation of this.